# PIV authentication on redhat

Tags: windows, redhat, domain, authentication, linux-networking

I'm looking for a solution, or set of technologies, (etc) - for setting up a mixed (win 7, rhel 6.5) network with centralized login using smart cards (PIV).

I know that this is possible using a Windows Domain Controller, and joining the red hat and windows clients to the domain, and using active directory and windows certification services to manage the certs.

What I'd like to know is if this is possible using a redhat server with samba-winbind to emulate a domain controller, and what, if any third-party software will support this.  I know that solutions like Centrify might support this, but their documentation seems to indicate that a Windows server is required.

Comment: Did you take a look at samba4? The windows client expects the CA certificate to be published in the correct trusted root stores. It expects the domain controller to talk ldapS, i.e. your linux based domain controller needs to have a domain controller certificate, which needs to be derived from the correct template. The right Miscrosoft OIDs need to be included in the certificate. This is fairly complicated to do it from the scratch. I do not know a product...